# Multiline expression for Atom language grammar

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I am writing a language highlighting package for a scripting language. The comments in this language starts with a number sign `#` and ends in the same line unless the last character is an ampersand `&`. This is what I tried.

```
{
    'comment': 'Comments'
    'begin': '#'
    'end': '[^&]$'
    'name': 'punctuation.definition.comment'
    'patterns': [
        {
            'include': 'text.todo'
        }
    ]
}
```

But this fails and works as a simple dollar sign`$`. Atom is based in [TextMate](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) that uses [Oniguruma](https://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions) regular expressions. This should work but it does not (neither a lookbehind `(?<!&)$`). Curiously enough the 'inverse matching' `[&]$` works perfectly.

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

My version of Atom is:

```
 Atom    : 1.10.2
 Electron: 0.37.8
 Chrome  : 49.0.2623.75
 Node    : 5.10.0
```

Comment: If you need a negative lookbehind, it should be `(?<!&)$` or `$(?<!&)`, not `(!<!&)$`

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew you are right, I made a typo (here, not when I tried in Atom). Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know why `(?<!&)$` does not work, but `(?<!&)\n` does it perfectly:

```
{
    'comment': 'Comments'
    'begin': '#'
    'end': '(?<!&)\n'
    'name': 'punctuation.definition.comment'
    'patterns': [
        {
            'include': 'text.todo'
        }
    ]
}
```

I will try to find out why the regular expressions with the end of the string (the dollar sign `$`) does not work and update this answer.